# How do you pass parameters from one component to another using react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component with a link to another component and would like to pass data to it (to show the details of the object).  *I would think this would be simple, but just can't seem to get this to work!*

So I have a component with a link:

```
export const Person = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h4>{this.props.person.get('full_name')}</h4>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Link to="/person/detail" params={person: this.props.person}>View Details</Link>
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```

And want to pass the person details to this component:

```
export const PersonDetails = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
          {console.log(this.props.person)}
          <h4>The Details...</h4>
        </div>
        <Link to="/person">Back</Link>
    );
  }
});
```

And the console.log shows undefined.  What am I missing here?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you checked `this.props.params` in `PersonDetails` ?

Comment: Thanks Phi, I tried and got excited when it showed an Object, but unfortunately the Object ended up being empty {}.

Comment: I checked their API. There is no `params` props in `Link` component. You can take a look at their example for query params here : https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/query-params/app.js

Comment: Thanks again Phi!  This seems hacky to me though, the person object can be fairly complex (30+ fields), and passing through the url seems like a work-around.  We already have the object in client memory, I would think this would be trivial to do...

Comment: passing data like this seems better accomplished through a person store as opposed to your router

Comment: I think you are right @GrumbleSnatch, I'm exploring a way to pass just the Id and then get the person from the store.  Still seems like there should be the ability to do this functionality though...

Comment: Oh; in that case, you can define the path for your person route to include an id.  How you proceed will depend heavily on your version of react-router, but check out the example here:  https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#link